# SSRS Cells auto-merge

Tags: excel, reporting-services, rows

I'm having trouble unmerging cells on the report.

[3 Suppliers for the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvN3r.png)

I have a SQL query that shows 3 instances of a supplier (left joined to contact) as shown below. However, when running the report for the query the 3 instance of the supplier is merged into one. This is not desirable in my case because when exporting the report to excel, I'd like to be able to sort columns based on other properties, however, this would not be possible due the the merging of the rows. How can I get results to show individually?
[Cells are Merged on the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQHOw.png)
[image: Report Design]

Comment: It would be more helpful to see a pic of your table in Design view with the table selected so the grouping lines appear on the left side. My guess is that you have multiple levels of grouping that is showing your supplier on the left and maybe other ungrouped data on the right. You'll just need to Delete the outer group but not delete any columns so it shows the detail. On the left of your table when selected, there should be just the three lines to indicate Detail and not a Parenthesis looking thing for Grouping.

Comment: @HannoverFist I've included a screenshot of the design view. I've tried deleting  the groupings, but this just resulted in a single query result

Answer (score 0):

Within the properties of each `Row Group` you can specify which columns to group on. You generally don't need a separate group for each field, but that's OK. In your last group, the one called "(Details)", if it is not grouped by anything, it will show one row per line of results from the query. So take a look at what it's grouped by. As long as the rows are in your dataset, the report will group or show them based on how you configure the grouping here. Grouping on nothing means it will show all rows.

Another tip is to align the end of your header textbox with the line of one of your columns. This will prevent it from creating an extra column in Excel for the "City" field.

Answer (score 0):

Your report does not need all of those groupings - the SSRS grouping is not like SQL. You should only group when you want to aggregate data on that field. Normally you might have a company with its address in various fields in one group but you only need to group once on the Company Name or (preferably) ID - not on each field and not a separate group for each. You could then show details of various invoices in other columns that aren't grouped.

But since you want to display the company data on each row, you would not want ANY grouping on the company.

To fix your issues, remove all the groupings (but not the rows) and just leave the detail group (which doesn't have a Grouping).

You can check out [MS Docs: Understanding Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/understanding-groups-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15) for a better explanation.